# How to stub method using Mockito in java

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a singleton class S which implements an interface I.
Singleton class has a method A which inturn calls method B.
I have to test method A.

This is my singleton Class

```
        public class S implements I{
           private static S INSTANCE = new S();

           public static I getInstance(){
             return INSTANCE;
           }

           public String methodA(){
              methodB();
           }
         }
```

This is how my method looks in the test class.

```
public void testMethodA(){
S so = S.getInstance();
S spy = Mockito.spy(so);
Mockito.doReturn(something).when(spy).methodB(); // I have to cut the dependency of this method B, hence will stub this 
String exp_value = 'X';
assertEquals(exp_value,spy.methodA);
}
```

The issue is, actual method B is called  instsead of the stub and hence my test fails.
Could anyone help and let me know if im doing anything wrong here.

Comment: Mockito.verify(so ).methodB().thenReturn(something)

Comment: How are you enforcing that this class is a singleton?  You're very likely doing it in a way that prevents Mockito from making the spy, since a spy is actually a new object, of a subclass of the original class.  You may have to reassess whether you really want to do this.

Comment: use Mock instead of Spy.

Comment: You do _not_ want to mock or spy subjects under test.

Comment: any other way to test this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code with a few modifications compiles and runs as expected. Here is a self contained running example.

```
public class StackOverflow59960713 {
    public interface I {
        String methodA();
    }

    public static class S implements I {
        private static S INSTANCE = new S();

        public static I getInstance() {
            return INSTANCE;
        }

        public String methodA() {
            return methodB();
        }

        public String methodB() {
            return "abc";
        }

    }

    @Test
    public void testMethodA() {
        S so = (S) S.getInstance();  <== getInstance() returns I not S
        S spy = Mockito.spy(so);
        Mockito.doReturn("123").when(spy).methodB();

        String exp_value = "123";
        assertEquals(exp_value, spy.methodA());  <=== methodA() not methodA
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, I did the necessary changes but still the real method is called in case of methodB()... I'm getting org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected "123 " but was "ABC".

Comment: What version of mockito are you using?

Comment: I'm using Java 8

Comment: Thanks, however I mean the version of the mockito library - like for example mockito-core-3.2.4.jar etc..

Comment: How do I check that

Comment: It all depends on what tooling you're using. Are you using an IDE like Eclipse, Netbeans or IntelliJ ? Are you using a build tool like Maven or Gradle?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206841/discussion-between-lisha-and-adam).

Comment: Issue is solved, there was an error in one of the parameter of the stubbed method. Thanks for the help